# How to Queue inbound Rest API request

Tags: apex, callout, apexrest

Is there a way, we can execute the inbound rest api callout to be queued like the outbound callout can be queued using future or Queueable interface?

Comment: You can certainly enqueue Asynchronous Apex functionality from your Apex REST service classes, like most other Apex contexts. Of course, you cannot also return a synchronous result from those code elements. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? (Please [edit]).

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why would you want this to be asynchronous?

Comment: Hello sfdcfox, This is not an X-Y Problem. We have parallel incoming rest api requests to update the same record with few seconds to milli seconds difference, due to which 3 out 4 requests failing to update the record. Please answer if you can.

Comment: I have a similar issue: multiple callouts in quick succession, sometimes updating the same record due to UPSERT dml, causing uncaught exceptions due to DUPLICATE_VALUE errors.  @SainathPinninti did you have any luck with a solution?